# I cannot connect my form to my models for posting of grades

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

**Models.py**

```
class YearLevel(models.Model):
   ...

class Section(models.Model):
   ...
class Subject(models.Model):
   ...

class Student(models.Model):

   first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = '')
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = '')
   year_level = models.OneToOneField(YearLevel, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True)
   section = models.OneToOneField(Section, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True)
   enrolled_subject = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)
   parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True) #parent is from user models

class StudentGrade(models.Model):

   PERIOD_CHOICES = [
       ...
   ]

   student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
   period = models.CharField(choices=PERIOD_CHOICES, max_length = 30)
   subjects = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   grade = models.DecimalField(default = 75.00, max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
```

**Views.py**

```
def postgrade(request):

students = Student.objects.all().prefetch_related('enrolled_subject')
context = {
    'students': students,
}

if request.method == "POST":
    data = request.POST
    grade_list = data.getlist('grade')
    subject_list = data.getlist('subject')

    student = Student.objects.get(pk= data.get('studentid'))   #this is where they point my error

    i=0
    while i < len(grade_list):
        enrolled_subject = Subject.objects.get(pk= subject_list[i])
        new_grade = StudentGrade(student = student, period= data.get('period'), subjects = enrolled_subject, grade=grade_list[i])
        new_grade.save()
        i+= 1
```

**Postgrade.html(template)**

My queries are displaying properly, the problem is I get an error when i try to save the form

```
{% for students in students %}
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse{{forloop.counter}}" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse{{forloop.counter}}">
    {{students.first_name}} {{students.last_name}}
  </a>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapse{{forloop.counter}}">
  <div class="card card-body">
    <form method="POST" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="studentid" value="{{students.student.id}}">
        <label for="period">Period:</label>
        <select name="period" required>
            <option selected>First Grading</option>
            <option>Second Grading</option>
            <option>Third Grading</option>
            <option>Fourth Grading</option>
        </select><br>

    {% for subject in students.enrolled_subject.all %}
        <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="{{subject.id}}">
        <label for="{{subject.subject_name}}">{{subject.subject_name}}</label>
        <input type="text" name="grade">
        <br>
    {% endfor %}

                <button type="submit">upload grade</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

My error says:
ValueError at /Information/postgrade/

invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

and it points to my views.py:

```
student = Student.objects.get(pk= data.get('studentid'))
```

So i feel like there might be something wrong with my template or views, or maybe both

or I should drop out LOL

Thanks for the help

Comment: check the grade, subject, and student ids are received as expected in the view.

Comment: That means `data.get('studentid')` returns `''`

Comment: @Sumithran, the problem is the site is uploaded in pythonanywhere and I cant seem to print from views.py

Comment: @bdbd yes, seems so, but I do not know how to fix it, maybe theres another way to help the form identify which student I am refering to when saving?

Comment: run this in the local machine and check it out.

Comment: Im sorry, i hade a lot of issues lately and i dont have my own computer cuz it broked, so afew days before my defense(which is in 12hrs from when im typing this comment), i borrowed a new computer, just to get through my project presentation,                                                 And I just want to add, that I found the issue in this question and I want to close it, because my error is i think, "mistaken spelling" sorry for taking up your time ```<input type="hidden" name="studentid" value="{{students.student.id}}">``` should be ```{{students.id}}```